# Why assigning a reference to a non-reference will change its dynamic behavior

Tags: c++

I have the following codes to dynamically allocate a class object in a function call:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A(){std::cout<<"Constructing..."<<std::endl;}
        ~A(){std::cout<<"Deconstructing..."<<std::endl;}
};

A & f() 
{
    std::cout<<"Calling f()"<<std::endl;
    A * pa = new A();
    std::cout<<"End calling f()"<<std::endl;
    return *pa;
}

int main()
{
    A & b = f();
}
```

The output are:

```
Calling f()
Constructing...
End calling f()
```

which means that the class object was never deleted.

However, if I change the line in `main` to:

```
    A b = f();
```

the outputs are:

```
Calling f()
Constructing...
End calling f()
Deconstructing...
```

which means the class object was deleted automatically.

Why that assigning a reference to a non-reference will change its dynamic behavior?

Comment: Only `b` is destroyed in the second, not `*pa`. C++ has value semantics. References are the exception.

Comment: @chris If `b` is copied from `*pa` in the second case, why there is not constructor called here?

Comment: @HailiangZhang: Because it's copied (or moved), using the copy (or move) constructor. You're only printing from the default constructor, which isn't used here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Can the compiler even make that move?

Comment: @Mike Seymour, my bad! Now that there is a memory leaking in the second case, I think!

Comment: @HailiangZhang, Both of them have the same problem. You never call `delete`.

Comment: @chris: It can't; I was typing faster than I was thinking. My answer is more accurate than the comment that I unfortunately can't fix now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no change to the dynamic object created by `new`. That's not destroyed in either case, since it can only be destroyed by explicit use of `delete`.

In the second case, you create a second object `b` by copying the dynamic object. Being automatic, that is destroyed when it goes out of scope, so you see a `Deconstructing...` message from that.

Since it was initialised by a copy constructor, not the default constructor, you don't see a corresponding `Constructing...` message. You could add a copy constructor to see that:

```
A(A const &){std::cout<<"Copying..."<<std::endl;}
```

giving the output

```
Calling f()
Constructing...
End calling f()
Copying...
Deconstructing...
```

In general, always use smart pointers and other RAII types to manage dynamic resources, to avoid memory leaks and other lifetime confusion issues.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of

```
A & b = f();
```

`b` refers to the object created on the heap.

In the case of

```
A b = f();
```

`b` creates a copy (possible move) of the data on the heap. This one is destructed when the function exits (when `b` goes out of scope).

The object on the heap is left alone, in both cases.

To explore this further, the addition of the copy constructor would help `A(A const&)` and then printed a message, or even making it `private` and noting the compilation errors aid in marking the copies and their locations.

Note: when you `new` an object in a function and then don't destroy it, or don't move the pointer to some other owner, you will leak memory. Favour library utilities like `unique_ptr` or `share_ptr` to manage the resource (RAII).

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a value type, it is constructed on the stack and the compiler takes care of calling its destructor when it goes out of scope. However, when you create the instance on the heap by calling `new`, the compiler can't know when the instance is not needed any more and therefor it's up to the programmer to indirectly call its destructor by using `delete`. The fact that you have a reference to the object on the heap doesn't provide the compiler with any knowledge of when the object has to be destroyed.